# transfer <div> tag into an .js file

Tags: javascript

This is a part of my page in the html:

```
<div id="FJ_TF_Cont" style="position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-width: 0px; width: 200px;">
    <iframe width="210" height="640" src="../test/content.html" name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">

    </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to transfer these contents into an .js file, instead of writing this piece of html in every page as this appears in many html pages. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dominique Fortin's post, without JQuery:

**yourscript.js:**

```
var _html = '<div id="FJ_TF_Cont" style="position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-width: 0px; width: 200px;">'
    +'<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../test/content.html" name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
    +'</iframe>'
    +'</div>';

document.write(_html);
```

**index.html:**

```
<head>
  <script src="yourscript.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
<body>
```

As long as yourscript.js is executed before the page is completely loaded, it will not overwrite your page.

Answer (score 2):

**forall.js**

```
    var _html = '<div id="FJ_TF_Cont" style="position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-width: 0px; width: 200px;">'
        +'<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../test/content.html" name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
        +'</iframe>'
        +'</div>';

document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = _html;
```

Use this `.js` in any `.html` file having `div` with `id` equal to `some_id`

Answer (score 0):

On your snippet.js:

```
//files/js/snippet.js
var html_snippet = '<div id="FJ_TF_Cont"...  </iframe></div>';
```

Load:

```
<script src="snippet.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("hook").innerHTML = html_snippet;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply grab the element and it's contents, you can use `document.getElementById`.

```
var div = document.getElementById("FJ_TF_Cont");
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
var _html = '<div id="FJ_TF_Cont" style="position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-width: 0px; width: 200px;">'
    +'<iframe width="210" height="640" src="../test/content.html" name="FJIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width: 210px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 1;">'
    +'</iframe>'
    +'</div>';

$(document).ready( function () {
   $('body').append(_html);
});
```

Comment: No jQuery allowed, it's a pure js question.

Comment: The Tag  wiki says: "answers to questions questions tagged with this tag are expected to be in pure-java script unless another library is mentioned or tagged."